# What has to be my code look like, to be as clean as possible?

Tags: embedded, coding-style

I'm writing a library for LCD screen. In documentation it is said, that:

`If you want to clear screen, you have to first put curson on it's begin`

I've got 2 functions written, no matter how are they implemented,it's just all about
readability.

`LCD_Clear_Screen()` 
`LCD_Put_Cursor_In_Position(int row, int column)`

To put curson in begin of screen - function has to be like

`LCD_Put_Cursor_In_Position(0, 1);`

And there is my question. Is it better to put this line straight into LCD_Clear_Screen
function? If I would do so, user won't have to write it every time before clearing screen by himself.

However in book "Clean Code" author said that function has to be responsible only for one thing
to keep code clean - and it would be breaking of this rule cause function which is clearing screen is also putting cursor in some specific position.

What do you thing, which option would be better?

Comment: What happens if the cursor is not at (0, 1)? Does the LCD only clear from the cursor to the end?

Comment: Then the function simply does not work

Comment: Those functions are about the LCD, so should be separate since they are separate in the functioning of an LCD screen.  An application that uses this may have its own notion of "ClearDisplay", which might reposition the cursor, or make it disappear, fill the display with a pattern etc..   Thus it is critical that the device library avoid *overreach* so that the application doesn't have to subvert it.

Comment: Speculating about your code isn't very meaningful without seeing the code. Generally, it's fine to have functions belonging to the same translation unit call each other however you like. Decent compilers will inline such calls when it thinks it makes sense.

Comment: For library user to have a happy coding function name should reflect what it does and do not have any side effects. According to your quoted documentation moving cursor is prerequisite for clear function to work properly at HW side. So move cursor instruction HAS to reside in a clear screen function. I would rephrase your question as "Should I move cursor back to the position last known to the library user?" - I would say that you have to restore position of cursor to keep function names meaningless.